# Adafruit feather M0, determinating UART pins. I dont know which pins are RX and TX

Tags: uart

I want to connect MAX3232 to adafruit feather M0 board https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-basic-proto/overview ,
but I cant decide which pins to use for uart rx and tx. In the controller data sheet they talk about SERCOM register https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2772/atmel-42181-sam-d21_datasheet.pdf
So basically I dont know how to determine rx and tx on a board.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: downvote for not  doing your own research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right here, [Adafruit Feather M0 Basic Proto - Pinouts](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-basic-proto/pinouts), lower right corner of the second picture (first photograph) of the board

[image: Adafruit Feather M0 Basic Proto board]

Comment: I upvoted this answer because you did a simple research and posted a right answer, but the OP didn't deserved to receive an answer for something so simple that he could have researched himself.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the adafruit page in your first link. Click on "PINOUT" on the left side. Look for the pins marked RX and TX in the pretty diagram.

Comment: There is even silkscreen text on the board that says 'tx' and 'rx'...